# PHP classes: Adding additional parameters to extended class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have upgraded to PHP 5.4 and now I get this error message and I know why I'm getting the message but need to find out how to fix it.  I know it's because I have additional parameters in the child class when it extends the parent class validate() method.

> Strict Standards: Declaration of ValidateName::validate() should be
>   compatible with Validator::validate($validateThis) in
>   C:\www\testing\ValidateName.php on line 4

I have seen on here that some people say to use func_get_args() but other people say not to use it.

How can I get rid if this error?

My parent class

```
    //Constructor
    public function validate($validateThis) {}

    // Function to add all the error messages to the array
    public function setError($msg) {
        $this->errors[] = $msg;
    }

    // Function to check if the validation passes
    public function isValid() {
        if (count($this->errors) > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Function to get each of the errors
    public function fetch() {
        $error = each($this->errors);
        if ($error) {
            return $error['value'];
        } else {
            reset($this->errors);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and my child class

```
    class ValidateName extends Validator {
        public function ValidateName ($name, $field) {
            //  Create an array of errors
            $this->errors = array();
            // Validate the text for that field
            $this->validate($name, $field);
        }  

        public function validate() {

            // If any of the text fields are empty add an error message to the array
            if(empty($name)) {
                $this->setError($field.' field is empty');
            }
            else {
                // Validate the text fields against the regex.  If it fails add error message to array
                if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z- ]+$/', $name)) {
                    $this->setError($field.' contains invalid characters');
                }
                // if the length of the field is less than 2, add error message to array
                if (strlen($name) < 2) {
                    $this->setError($field.' is too short'); 
                }
                // if the length of the field greater than 30, add error message to array
                if (strlen($name) > 50) {
                    $this->setError($field.' is too long');
                }
            }    
        }    
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should fix that by not altering how that method behaves. Method *implementations* may differ, but method *signatures* should stay unchanging. Otherwise you're talking about a different method, not an alternative implementation of the same method. That's the point the notice is trying to get across.

Answer (score 1):

- The `// constructor` comment is wrong, since the class name is `Validator`, please improve your question :-)
- You could 'fix' it by adding an `$ignored` parameter to the child's `validate()` method, but maybe this is a design problem: you should decide if the object to be validated is passed as a parameter to the `validate` method or during construction (this choice changes slightly the nature of you class)
- Either way, the child class should be consistent with the parent, according to the
  [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 0):

The method-constructor since `PHP 5.3.3` is

`__construct`

So you have to use:

```
class ValidateName extends Validator {
    public function __construct($name, $field) { //It must not be ValidateName
        //  Create an array of errors
        $this->errors = array();
        // Validate the text for that field
        $this->validate($name, $field);
    } 
}
```

Construtors of derived classes may differ from parents', but if you write `public function ClassName()`, it is treated as a usual method, and when derived, you should implement the parameters it must accept.

Comment: `__construct` is not required. You also can use the classname for non-namespaced classes.

Comment: `__construct` was introduced in 5.0, not 5.3.3. I'm also not sure what this has to do with the question.